# How to solve Scikit learn preprocessing pipeline error with Numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, nlp, data-preprocessing

I am using scikit-learn to build a classifier that predicts if two sentences are paraphrases or not (e.g. paraphrases: How tall was Einstein vs. What was Albert Einstein's length).

My data consists of 2 columns with strings (phrase pairs) and 1 target column with 0's and 1's (= no paraphrase, paraphrase). I want to try different algorithms.

I expect the last line of code below to fit the model. Instead, the pre-processing Pipeline keeps producing an error I cannot solve: "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'."

The code is below and I have isolated the error happening in the last line shown (for brevity I have excluded the rest). I suspect it is because the target column contains 0s and 1s, which cannot be turned lowercase.

I have tried the answers to similar questions on stackoverflow, but no luck so far.

How can you work around this?

```
question1               question2                        is_paraphrase
How long was Einstein?  How tall was Albert Einstein?    1
Does society place too  How do sports contribute to the  0
much importance on      society?
sports?                 
What is a narcissistic  What is narcissistic personality 1  
personality disorder?   disorder?
```

======

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

para = "paraphrases.tsv"

df = pd.read_csv(para, usecols = [3, 5], nrows = 100, header=0, sep="\t")

y = df["is_paraphrase"].values
X = df.drop("is_paraphrase", axis=1).values
X = X.astype(str) # I have tried this
X = np.char.lower(X)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3, 
random_state = 21, stratify = y)

text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()), 
('clf', MultinomialNB())])

text_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Your train dataset consist of two columns right ? `question1` and `question2` ?

Comment: Yes the training set has two columns.

Comment: You can use [TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) in place of CountVectorizer and TfidfTransformer, which will simplify this. But you will need to process one column at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not because of the last column, it is because your Train xdataset will contain two columns `question1` and `question2`. Now this will result in you `X_train` having each row as list of values. So when the `CountVectorizer` is trying to convert it into lower case, it is returning an error since a numpy.ndarray does not contain lower function.

To overcome this problem you need to split the dataset `X_train` into two parts, say `X_train_pt1` and `X_train_pt2`. Then perform CountVectorizer on these indiviudally, followed by tfidfTransformer on each individual result. Also ensure that you same object for transformation on these datasets.

Finally you stack these two arrays together and give it as input to your classifier. You can find a similar [implementation here](https://gist.github.com/Sentimentron/3a93eb22453270761ad65071e4a57dc0).

**Update :**
I think the following should be of some help (I admit this code can be further improved for more efficiency):

```
def flat_list(my_list):
    return [str(item) for sublist in my_list for item in sublist]


def transform_data(trans_obj_list,dataset_splits):
    X_train = dataset_splits[0].astype(str)
    X_train = flat_list(X_train)

    for trfs in trans_obj_list:
        transformed_vector = trfs().fit(X_train)
        for x in xrange(0,len(dataset_splits)):
            dataset_splits[x] =flat_list(dataset_splits[x].astype(str))
            dataset_splits[x]=transformed_vector.transform(dataset_splits[x])

    return dataset_splits

new_X_train,new_X_test = transform_data([CountVectorizer,TfidfTransformer],[X_train,X_test])
```

Comment: Would it also be possible to lower-case the X_train separately and "switch off" the lowercasing in CountVectorizer? That way the code could be kept much shorter (and faster).

Comment: Even if you somehow "switch-off" the lower casing (Although that's not possible) the CountVectorizer is implemented to work on a single string rather than a list of strings. You will have to change the whole implementation. So a better thing would to make a generic function that accepts the tfIdfTransformer or CountVectorizor object and performs the transformation and return the data accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Have tried your revised answer but now run into a new error: TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('<U76'),). Not sure what it means but trying to fix it.

Comment: @twhale it basically means that your data contains some unicode characters and you need to encode them into ascii to work correctly, since the transformation functions are implemented to work on ascii strings only. If you found this answer useful, can you please upvote and mark this answer as the correct one ?